# Pandas .title() when string has an 's

Tags: python, pandas

I converted a string in a Pandas dataframe to title case. However, when I do, anything directly after an apostrophe becomes uppercase as well. How do I correct this?

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.title())
df['name'] = df['name'].replace("\'S", "\'s")
df.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid 'later fixing', one idea could be to split the string on the space and uppercase first letter of each word:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(
    lambda string: ' '.join(map(str.capitalize, string.split()))
)
```

Following @shriakhilc interesting suggestion, there is also an equivalent built-in way of doing this with the [string.capwords](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.capwords) method:

```
from string import capwords

df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(capwords)
```

Comment: A built-in way to do this is `df[cols].applymap(string.capwords)`. This method is mentioned in the [docs for str.title()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) and does the same thing as your lambda. May not be worth an extra import for just this though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try enable the `regex` parameter

```py
df['name'] = df['name'].replace("'S", "'s", regex=True)
```

Or use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```py
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace("'S", "'s")

# To fix multiple columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda col: col.str.replace("'S", "'s"))
```

Comment: Thank you! These worked very well. I appreciate the help.